# Disable laptop pointing stick

Tags: hardware, laptop

How do I disable the [pointing stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick) of a laptop (that mouse pointer in the middle of the keyboard)?

The only option available in the BIOS also disables the Touchpad, so it needs to be done from the OS.

Comment: At work most people just removed the rubber top to the pointer and ignored it.  Possibly the simplest answer!

Answer (score 6):

#### 1 - Use xinput to identify the device

Example on a Dell Latitude E6410

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Logitech USB Optical Mouse       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
     ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Power Button                             id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Video Bus                                id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Power Button                             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Sleep Button                             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_3M: In          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

#### 2 - Use xinput to disable the device

```
xinput -set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0
```

#### 3 - Execute the command on startup

To disable it for all users (and for the graphical login window), one can run it as root on startup using `cron`. This is the preferred way if the trackpoint is broken and root privileges are granted on the machine.

Disabling as user may depend on the desktop environment.

Typically, one would put the command in a script

```
#!/bin/sh
xinput -set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0
```

make the script executable (`chmod + x`) and call it on startup.

It is absolutely equivalent to call the command line directly without writing it in a script. Just a matter of preference. The script is a nice way to record the command in case it would be accidentaly removed from the startup commands.

Source : [Disabling the track stick in Ubuntu](https://cederlys.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/disabling-the-track-stick-in-ubuntu/)